# Cannot use functional test plugin on grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to use the functional test plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test) for grails.  In my build config, I do:

```
plugins {
    ...
    compile ":functional-test:2.0.RC1"
}
```

When I do

```
grails compile
```

or

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

I get:

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of grails are you running?

Comment: @JacobASeverson I am running grails 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I use version 1.2.7 but I see the same thing the first time I run compile (or anything that triggers dependency resolution). But the second time I do it, everything works fine.